# Table filtering and maintaining the state after refresh

Tags: jquery

I have a table containing data fro db, what I wan't to accomplish is filter (only one column) according to check-boxes without post back and save the filter status if the user refresh the page..

- check-boxes- when checking a check-box, i'll send the text near to it to the to Jquery "contains" function

Example:(check-box)

| | show only size 10

here I send 10 to "contains)(if the user check the check-box) and the table will show only size 10 shoes. other ones will be deleted..

- using asp.net

what I thought(don't really know if it is a good solution) is:

use Jquery "contains" function if the column contains the text then ok else delete the entire row.. efficient, no? can I maintain the filtering after refresh
Can someone simplify it for me and help me to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1) Make your action button call send a AJAX request to the server which includes the values of all the checkboxes.

2) Make your server code a web service .asmx which would call a stored procedure with these values as parameters.

3) Write a stored procedure which will dynamically construct the SQL Query depending on the checkbox values passed in.

4) Get some JSON back from the AJAX call and use this data to render the correct columns on the page.

The state will be maintained throughout

Comment: Thanks, it very abstract for me to try:)
I saw another good solution-> use Jquery "contains" function if the column contains the text then ok
else 
delete the entire row.. 
sounds very efficient, no? 
I just don't no how to maintain the filtering after refresh

Comment: Can You help me maintaining the filtering after refresh (using contains)?

Comment: It would be less efficient to retrieve the whole table and then filter, than it would be to only retrieve the columns you need in the first place. It depends what your server-side stack is as to how you would go about maintaining state on refresh.